# R: Erasing Lines on ggplot2 - drawing half rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I generated some random data and plotted the following graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

var_1 = rnorm(1000,20,20)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,20,20)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2)

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

**I now want to make the following pattern on this graph:**

[image]

I tried to do this with the following code, but this is the closest I could get:

```
a1 = ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + 
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color = "red") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, color = "red")

a2 = a1 + geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=50, color = "red") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=50, color = "red")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Could someone please show me a "direct" way to make this pattern on this graph? Is there some way to "erase" these extra lines?

Suppose I had a data frame ("my_points") that looked like this:

```
my_points = data.frame(var_1_point_1 = 0, var_1_point_2 = 50, var_2_point_1 = 0, var_2_point_2 = 50)
```

Could the graph be made using "my_data", and the lines be made by "referencing" the points in "my_points"? For example, something like this:

```
a1 = ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + 
      geom_point()+ 
      geom_hline(yintercept my_points[1,2], color = "red") + 
      geom_vline(xintercept=my_points[1,1], color = "red")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `geom_segment` instead of `geom_hline` or `geom_vline` since you'll need to specify `xend` and `yend` for each segment.

```r
library(tidyverse)

var_1 = rnorm(1000,20,20)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,20,20)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2)

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -50, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = 0), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = -50), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -50, xend = 50, y = 50, yend = 50), color = "red") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 50, xend = 50, y = 50, yend = -50), color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Update

Since OP wish to use an extra dataframe, here is the updated code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

var_1 = rnorm(1000,20,20)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,20,20)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2)

mypoint <- data.frame(var_1_point_1 = c(-50, 0), 
                      var_1_point_2 = c(0, -50), 
                      var_2_point_1 = c(-50, 50), 
                      var_2_point_2 = c(50, -50))

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_step(data = mypoint, aes(var_1_point_1, var_1_point_2), color = "red") +
  geom_step(data = mypoint, aes(var_2_point_1, var_2_point_2), color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ Benson: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there a way to "shorten" your answer? For example, suppose I say var_1_point_1 = 0, var_1_point_2 = 50, var_2_point_1 = 0, var_2_point_2 = 50 . Suppose I have  a data frame ("my_points") with 4 columns : var_1_point_1, var_1_point_2, var_2_point_1, var_2_point_2 . Could this graph that you made been produced using "my_data" and "my points"? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob see my updated answer :)

Answer (score 1):

People tend to forget about `geom_linerange` - in vanilla ggplot sadly only available for vertical lines. But there is also `ggstance::geom_linerangeh`. Those would allow you to pass a data frame with your x/y coordinates and you will "only" need two geom layers for vertical and for horizontal lines (if your lines always start at the edge of the plot). You could apply the same idea with geom_segment of course, then without need of another package.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

## changed data frame my points:
x <- y <- c(0, 50)
my_points <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = var_1, y = var_2), data = my_data) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = x, ymin = -Inf, ymax = y), data = my_points, color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_linerangeh(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = x, y = y), data = my_points, color = "red", size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! How would this change if you had 4 unique points? X1, X2, Y1, Y2 . Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob not sure what you mean with that?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to make your own stat and use this with geom_segment:

```r
library(ggplot2)

var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 20, 20)
var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 20, 20)

my_data <- data.frame(var_1, var_2)

## changed data frame my points:
x <- y <- c(0, 50)
my_points <- data.frame(x, y)

StatEdge <- ggproto("StatEdge", Stat, compute_group = function(data, scales) {
  x <- c(rep(-Inf, nrow(data)), data$x)
  y <- c(data$y, rep(-Inf, nrow(data)))
  xend <- rep(data$x, nrow(data))
  yend <- rep(data$y, nrow(data))
  data.frame(x, xend, y, yend)
})

## now you can use the new stat for your geom
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = var_1, y = var_2), data = my_data) +
  geom_segment(data = my_points, aes(x, y), stat = "edge", size = 2, color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>